# Positioning of Windows Form Application

Tags: winforms

How do I code the start location of my winform app such that it always starts in the bottom right hand corner of the screen. As using x and y coordinate only affects one particular screen resolution, on a smaller or larger screen the winform would not appear in the desired location.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do this in the OnLoad() method/event, one of the few real reasons to use it.  The form's actual size won't be the designed size because the user might have changed preferences like the window caption height or the form might be rescaled due to a different video DPI setting.  This is all sorted out when OnLoad() starts running.

Make it look like this:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        var scr = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location);
        this.Left = scr.WorkingArea.Right - this.Width;
        this.Top = scr.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Height;
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this on MSDN:

[Setting the Screen Location of Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984420%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Regards

Comment: hi, thank you for your reply. my question was not about how to position it using x and y but how to program it to always start at the bottom right hand corner of the screen despite the resolution size. is there any pre-defined values to that?